Error cargando FONTS en lista de UIKIT para XCODE 15.3
La presente es para consultar si alguien esta teniendo problemas con la carga de fuentes con la actualización de xcode 15.3, revise las demás versiones y se pueden cargar con normalidad
[![Xcode 15.1][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Ktmpe.png

Como se puede observar en la version 15.3, no carga en la lista las fuentes instaladas, pero se pueden invocar a nivel de código

Según la imagen de la pregunta está seleccionado los fonts de System, intentaste cambiar a Custom para que te muestre el listado?

Como se observa, esta seleccionada en el custom nunitosans, pero al momento de revisarla aparece no seleccionada, y si la revisas en la lista de los custom, no se encuentra la fuente aunque si se puede acceder desde código a la librería,

Agregaste el archivo .ttf al proyecto y la referencia en el .plist? Si puedes acceder desde el código, por qué lo necesitas en el storyboard?

Si, eso ya esta agregado, lo raro es que funcionaba en las versiones previas, como las 15.2 para atras, pero en esa version del xcode 15.3 es en donde esta el problema

Leo que desde la version Xcode 15  están corrigiendo esos errores (113624207) (FB12903371) con el font. A esperar a que Apple lo corrija en la 15.4.
